# Role of functional dependency in `Unfoldable` typeclass of Haskell Collection API

Tags: haskell, typeclass, functional-dependencies

Im trying to understand the design of Haskell's [`Data.Collection`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/collections-api-1.0.0.0/docs/Data-Collections.html) library, coming from a Scala-literate background.

It uses [Functional Dependencies](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functional_dependencies) (which have a [Scala analog](https://milessabin.com/blog/2011/07/16/fundeps-in-scala/)) but the way they're used doesn't make sense to me. In the `Unfoldable` class, reproduced below, the element type `i` is shown as *determined by* the collection type `c`.

> ```
> class Unfoldable c i | c -> i
> ```
>
> Class of collection with unobservable elements. It is the dual of the `Foldable` class.

Please explain the role that the dependency `c -> i` is playing here and the design intent, ideally with an example of usage?

Answer (score 7):

The constraint expressed by that functional dependency is that given a collection type `c`, the type of its items `i` is already determined. For example, if `c ~ [a]`, i.e. the collection is a list of `a`s, then we should be able to determine that `i ~ a`.

Without that functional dependency, we could have two instances e.g. `Unfoldable [a] a` (the obvious/intended instance) and `Unfoldable [a] [a]` (with something like `insert = concat`, `singleton = id`). If the typechecker then sees something like `empty :: [a]`, it would have no way of choosing which instance to use:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances #-}

class Unfoldable c i where
    empty :: c

instance Unfoldable [a] a where
    empty = []

instance Unfoldable [a] [a] where
    empty = []

xs :: [a]
xs = empty
```

This results in:

```
No instance for (Unfoldable [a] i0) arising from a use of `empty'
The type variable `i0' is ambiguous
Relevant bindings include
  xs :: [a]
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Unfoldable [a] a
  instance Unfoldable [a] [a]
In the expression: empty
In an equation for `xs': xs = empty
```